# Broken video download with FFmpeg. Is this a DRM issue?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm a member of a local movie platform. I'm watching the movie but the player is bad. I want to download and watch it with PowerDVD.

I downloaded the image and sound with FFmpeg. I tried it in all players.

But the image and sound are corrupted. How can I fix this, thank you.

This is the FFmpeg command I used:

```
ffmpeg -i "https://d10c0r8axq84q3.cloudfront.net/5bd2f293ac08fb00066d2b88/outputs/618b726896f0d30006546fe4/v3/dash-0/video-0-4.mp4" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "asdas.mp4"
```

I wrote this question translation. I don't speak English.

Comment: Please edit your question: You need to add more actual details to your question. Like what FFmpeg command you used and what the service is and such. Without actual details, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I downloaded the image and sound of the movie with this command. But the image and sound are distorted and cannot be watched. I think this is what they call drm protection.

Comment: @rampi “I downloaded the image and sound of the movie with this command.” What command? Please edit your question to add the actual command.

Comment: @Giacomo1968  This command:  ffmpeg -i "https://d10c0r8axq84q3.cloudfront.net/5bd2f293ac08fb00066d2b88/outputs/618b726896f0d30006546fe4/v3/dash-0/video-0-4.mp4" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "asdas.mp4"

Comment: Corrupted how? Unrecognizable, or just a little garbled?